# Azure function app to GCP Pub/Sub workload identity federation: 503 error: ('Unable to retrieve Identity Pool subject token', '')

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, azure-managed-identity, google-cloud-identity

I tried, to push messages from Azure function app to GCP Pub/Sub, using workload identity federation (for authentication).

Observations :

1. Instead of using Workload identity federation, if we use the service principal with private 'KEYs' of the GCP Service Account, the 'Azure Function App' is able to successfully publish message to the GCP pub/sub.
2. Instead of using 'Azure Function App', if I use an Azure VM and run the code from that VM, I can publish message using the workload identity Federation

Below are the changes that I made to run the code in Azure function app when compared with the code in Azure VM.

- Since Azure VM instance uses the Metadata service url (http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2019-08-01) the same is replaced
  with (http://<identity_endpoint>/msi/token?api-version=2019-08-01)
- With the url (http://<identity_endpoint>/msi/token?api-version=2019-08-01) I can generate token without any issues

Resources:

- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#gcloud
- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-workload-identity-federation#oidc_4
- sample json config - https://google.aip.dev/auth/4117 (search azure)

```
    import logging
    import os
    import json
    
    import azure.functions as func
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
    from google.auth import identity_pool
    import requests
    
    
    def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
        blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url("<blob storage url>")
        download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
        blob_data = download_stream.readall()
    
        jsonKey = json.loads(blob_data)
        
        endpoint=os.environ["IDENTITY_ENDPOINT"]
        
        endpoint_header=os.environ["IDENTITY_HEADER"]
        
        resource_uri = os.environ["RESOURCE_URI"]
        token_auth_uri = f"{endpoint}?resource={resource_uri}&api-version=2019-08-01"
        head_msi = {'X-IDENTITY-HEADER':endpoint_header}
        
        resp = requests.get(token_auth_uri, headers=head_msi)
        access_token = resp.json()
        logging.info(f"access_token: {access_token}")
    
        jsonKey_to_str = json.dumps(jsonKey)
        newJson = jsonKey_to_str.replace("http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=app://<app_url>",token_auth_uri)
        logging.info(f"jsonstring after substitute: {newJson}")
    
        final_json_key = json.loads(newJson)
        logging.info(f"jsonKey after substitute: {final_json_key}")
        
    
        credentials = identity_pool.Credentials.from_info(final_json_key)
        logging.info(f"credentials from IDP: {credentials.token}")
        scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
        publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(credentials=scoped_credentials)
        topic_path = publisher.topic_path("cpn-data-highway-test", "cpndata")
        data_str = f"Message number infinite"
        data = data_str.encode("utf-8")
        future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
        print(future.result())
```

```
Failure Exception: RetryError: Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling target function, 
last exception: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('Unable to retrieve Identity Pool subject token', '') 
Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", 
line 402, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", 
line 58, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", 
line 611, in _run_sync_func return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context, File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) File "/home/site/wwwroot/BlobTriggerExample/__init__.py"
, line 47, in main print(future.result()) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/futures.py"
, line 62, in result return super().result(timeout=timeout) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py"
, line 445, in result return self.__get_result() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py"
, line 390, in __get_result raise self._exception File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/_batch/thread.py"
, line 275, in _commit response = self._client.api.publish( File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/google/pubsub_v1/services/publisher/client.py"
, line 621, in publish response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py"
, line 154, in __call__ return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs) File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py"
, line 283, in retry_wrapped_func return retry_target( File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py"
, line 205, in retry_target raise exceptions.RetryError(
```

Comment: See if any of the answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69226126/14973743) SO question helps your situation.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the SO post, as I stated in question this goes fine with the Azure VM