# Failing to retrieve from the Google Compute Engine metadata service on Colab

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

Attempting to list the blobs in a google cloud bucket produces the following error:

```
TransportError: ("Failed to retrieve
http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true
from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Status: 404
Response:\nb''", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x796af24222f0>)
```

The error seems similar to one mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64992452/failed-to-retrieve-token-from-the-google-compute-engine-metadata-service-status) but their use-case seems quite specific to kubernetes and a bunch of non-related things.

Simple code to reproduce:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name='my_bucket')
list(bucket.list_blobs())
```

Same error for uploading data, downloading data, etc

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by running the following in colab first:

```
from google.colab import auth 
auth.authenticate_user()
```